# How can I reset the terraform settings so that they can be applied normally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Even if I delete .terraform or hcl, I cannot reset the old login information of terraform.
How can I reset the terraform settings so that they can be applied normally?

```
Error: google api: Error 403: [old mail adress] does not have storage.bukets.create access to the google cloud project
```

Comment: Terraform can use different methods for authorization: Application Default Credentials and service accounts. Which one are you using? 1) If you are using ADC, change the account that you are using `gcloud auth application-default login` (see David Carrancio's answer). 2) If you are specifying a service account in the HCL, use the correct one or use a service account instead of ADC. 3) If you do not know read the documentation on how Terraform authorization works and is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

This way, you will be able to login with your new email and the old one will be removed.